# asynchttpclient + netty - java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem

Tags: java, ssl, asynchttpclient

I would like to know the way to ignore certs while making https calls. I am presently getting the following exceptions while making calls using the asyn http client -

java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem

The following is my code -

> AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = Dsl.asyncHttpClient(Dsl.config()
>           .addRequestFilter(new ThrottleRequestFilter(mcph))
>           .setMaxConnections(mc)
>           .setIoThreadsCount(iot)
>           .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(mcph)
>           .setKeepAlive(true));

I am able to make calls successfully using the curl -k option. I want to mimic that behavior in async http client.

Regards,
Adi